# Array from MYSQLi - can't select specific array result

Tags: php, arrays, select, mysqli

following problem:

I need only the last array (the biggest one)
I get the following result with print_r:

```
Array ( [1] => 4800 ) 
Array ( [1] => 4800 [2] => 4700 ) 
Array ( [1] => 4800 [2] => 4700 [3] => 4900 ) 
Array ( [1] => 4800 [2] => 4700 [3] => 4900 [4] => 4900 ) 
Array ( [1] => 4800 [2] => 4700 [3] => 4900 [4] => 4900 [5] => 4800 )
```

But I only want the last one:

```
Array ( [1] => 4800 [2] => 4700 [3] => 4900 [4] => 4900 [5] => 4800 )
```

mysql/php select code:

```
   while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
   $p[$row['idd']] = $row['price'];

echo '<br>';


    print_r($p);    

}
```

Comment: put the print_r statement outside the loop then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put this as an explicit answer, even though the solution is fairly trivial because it seems you're new to this.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
   $p[$row['idd']] = $row['price'];
}
print_r($p);
```